# External database and Jquery mobile?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am writing an app in Jquery mobile, its a simple guessing game, true or false. I want to be able to add/delete to the database regularly to keep the game fresh, so I want to use a external database that the app references. When I am done I want to use phone gap to put the app on the markets.

What is the best practice for this? I am concerned about issues that may arise when I run the program through phone gap so I am wondering what you suggest. Do some db's work better than others, should I go with PHP Ajax.

Whats your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think everything you need is on the [Phonegap Storage Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).